# There was a problem in getting coordinates inside the image (not the main root window root tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

There was a problem in getting the coordinates inside the picture (not the main root window, the source code will be at the end), the image is loaded using cv2 and added to the application interface via label. How can I get coordinates when clicking the mouse only on the picture? If it is possible to do this through tkinter, again only inside the picture.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk


class interface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.panelA = None

        self.path = None
        self.s = None
        self.a = None

        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.f1 = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.f1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.f2 = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.f2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.e = tk.Entry(self.f1)
        self.e.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='ew')

        self.l1 = tk.Label(self.f1, text="Choose a picture")
        self.l1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ew')

        self.l2 = tk.Label(self.f1, text="Введите напор H, м")
        self.l2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')

        b1 = tk.Button(self.f1, text="Specify the file with the characteristic", command=self.select_image)
        b1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ew', columnspan=3)

        b2 = tk.Button(self.f1, text="select the pressure")
        b2.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='ew')

        columns = ['N', 'ny']
        self.table = ttk.Treeview(self.f1, columns=columns, show='headings', height=20)
        self.table.heading("N", text="N")
        self.table.heading("ny", text="%")
        self.table.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=3, sticky='ew')

        self.root.mainloop()

    def get_s(self):
        return self.s

    def select_image(self):
        self.path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

        if self.path:
            image = cv2.imread(self.path)

            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image = Image.fromarray(image)

            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

            if self.panelA is None:
                self.panelA = tk.Label(self.f2, image=image)
                self.panelA.image = image
                self.panelA.grid()

            else:
                self.panelA.configure(image=image)
                self.panelA.image = image


obj_interface = interface()
```

I tried it in tkinter, but it turned out to click only in the entire application

Comment: Stackoverflow is an English-Only site. Perhaps try [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events | After you initialize `self.panelA`, use `bind` to attach an event handler for either `<ButtonRelease-1>` or `<Button-1>` to it. Every time you click on the image, the even handler will get called, and the `event` will have its `x` and `y` components set to position of the click relative to top-left corner of the `Label`.